# Uso del verbo "sequestrare" in questo passaggio

Tags: word-usage, verbs, prepositions

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Felice voleva dedicarsi alle carte prima del rientro dei *pezzi grossi* senza così destar sospetti né dover rendere conto a nessuno. Studiò lo studiabile cercando di riunire gli appunti bastanti per un quadro esaustivo e al contempo confuso qualora smarrisse o **fosse sequestrato** del giallo taccuino giacché la polizia franchista poteva frugare impunemente le tasche della gente.

Immagino che il significato di "sequestrare" in questo passaggio corrisponda all'accezione numero 1 del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sequestrare): la polizia franchista poteva sequestrare il taccuino di Felice, cioè, poteva togliere questo taccuino a Felice. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire come questo verbo viene usato in questo brano. 
Perché il soggetto del verbo è lui (Felice)? Perché si usa la preposizione "del" dopo il verbo?

Comment: In effetti è una costruzione strana, che non ho presente. Sembra che l'autore usi il verbo “sequestrare”, ma costruendolo come se fosse “privare” (“fosse privato del taccuino”).

Comment: Licenza di scrittore...

Comment: Ma scusa, si tratta di un romanzo in versione originale o tradotto?

Comment: @Nico: Si tratta dell'originale. Perché dovrebbe essere una traduzione?

Comment: Chi è Francesco Luti? In rete, con una ricerca molto superficiale, trovo una persona con questo nome che si occupa di comunicazione aziendale. È lo stesso?

Comment: @DaG:  Vedi [qui](http://www.poliscritture.it/2019/04/01/la-goccia-che-scava-di-francesco-luti/) e [qui](http://www.francescoluti.com/).

Comment: @charo Non l'avevo trovato in rete e pensavo che potesse essere un autore spagnolo.

Comment: @Nico: Forse conoscete lo [zio](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giorgio_Luti), che è più noto.

Comment: Grazie, @Charo. Vedo che l'autore adesso vive a Barcellona. Per caso in castigliano o in catalano c'è un verbo simile a “sequestrare” che si costruisce in questo modo? Se sì potrebbe essere un'interferenza fra lingue simili.

Comment: No, @DaG: se fosse così, probabilmente non mi sarebbe sembrato un costrutto strano.

Comment: Il senso è quello di privare, per cui se dici  “fosse privato del taccuino” la frase non suona male. La stessa frase con “sequestrato” è sicuramente insolita ma non scorretta.

Comment: Si tratta probabilmente di una scelta stilistica particolare di cui la letteratura italiana e piena. Questo uso insolito di un verbo mi ricorda in un certo senso il sonetto foscoliano “In morte del fratello Giovanni” in cui il verbo “gemere” viene utilizzato in maniera transitiva: “gemendo il fior de’ tuoi gentili anni caduto”. Malgrado si tratti di poesia, che ha un suo insieme di regole grammaticali e sintattiche, l’utilizzo insolito del predicato deriva da una scelta stilistica particolare ma non errata e dunque suppongo si tratti di una situazione analoga.